# Is there a way to hold references to objects without interfering with their regular garbage collection?

Tags: javascript, reference, garbage-collection

I'm trying to make a signal based system for my Javascript application and i have something similar to this:

```
class EventHubListener {
    constructor(eventName, callback, errorHandling) {
        this.eventName = eventName;
        this.callback = callback;
        this.errorHandling = errorHandling;
    }
}

class EventsHub {

    constructor() {
        this.listeners = [];
        this.idgen = 0;
        this.defaultErrorHandler = null;
    }

    registerListener(listenerInstance) {// EventHubListener
        this.listeners.push(listenerInstance);
        return listenerInstance.id = ++idgen;
    }

    register(eventName, callback, errorHandling) {
        return registerListener(new EventHubListener(eventName, callback, errorHandling));
    }

    watchRemoteChange(type, field, callback, handling) {
        return register('EvtRemoteStateChange', (data)=> {
            if(!data || data.ObjectType !== type || !data.ChangedObject)
                return;
            callback(data.changedObject.id, data.ChangedObject[field]);
        }, handling);
    }

    unregisterListener(id) {
        this.listeners = this.listeners.filter(i=> i.id != id);
    }

    raise(eventName, data) {
        this.listeners.forEach(l=> l.eventName === eventName, listener=> {
            try {
                if(listener.eventName === eventName)
                    listener.callback(data);
            } catch(err) {
                if(listener.errorHandling) {
                    try {
                        listener.errorHandling(err);
                    } catch(internalError) {
                        this.handleError(internalError);
                    }
                } else {
                    this.handleError(err);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    handleError(err) {
        if(this.defaultErrorHandler) {
            try {
                this.defaultErrorHandler(err);
            } catch(errorHandlingError) {
                console.trace('Error in the default error handling routine', err, errorHandlingError);
            }
        } else {
            throw internalError;
        }
    }
}

// use
hub.watchRemoteChange('Products', 'SellingPrice', (id, value)=> {
    console.writeLine(`Product ${id} has changed price to ${value}!`);
});
```

My problem here is that I suppose that this "use" example will make the Hub class hold a reference to this annonymous function:

```
(id, value)=> {
    console.writeLine(`Product ${id} has changed price to ${value}!`);
}
```

Which in this example doesn't seem a big problem, but it could be using values from the closure which would be eventually collected in case the user class is collected (I guess?), the thing I need here is a way to detect that the user class has been disposed and make the hub class stop holding them or their closures and possibly avoid executing broken closures, is there a way to do that in the library side or do I have to manually always manage unregistering my listeners from user code?

Comment: Have you looked at `WeakMap` , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap

Comment: I didn't know of this one, I'll see what I can do. I'm supposing that I could have a WeakMap in the listener instance with the weak "hostObject" as a key, and then check on the listener if this WeakMap length is > 0 to determine if I should execute its function or auto-unregister that listener, could work.

Comment: To be honest, I just read your title.  But looking at your use case, not sure it will help.  WeakMap's unfortunately don't have a length property.  EventListeners I suppose will always be strongly linked, so without explicitly un-registering an event, there is no way the GC can know it's no longer required.  I did once use WeakMaps for doing server side event-listeners that would auto-cleanup on client disconnect, but this used a simple reference counting WeakMap and a cleanup timer that checked the ref-count.  But this still required a trigger of the client disconnect.

Comment: Yep, seems to be the case, my point here is to just have the event hub class unregister listeners by itself without the need for users class to manage releasing these. This part of the code is supposed to work on an Angular application, the hub component is a service and the components in this context are supposed to be able to register listeners for their lifetime, but those listeners should be cleared up when the component is unloaded; I just need the hub class to clear up the correct listeners instead of executing broken code that references cleared regions.